# Is it possible to load two different ole com libraries with the same GUID/CLSID at the same time in C#

Tags: c#, dll, com, ole

I have three vendor supplied ole com libraries that provide an interface to different but similar devices.  These libraries are not compatible between devices, and have differing functions embedded.  They also all share the same ID's, so I can only register one on a machine at a time.  Unfortunately I do not have the source and have no way of recompiling these.

My problem is that quite often I need to be able to communicate with more than one model of device.

I've tried loading the dll from a specific path and converting it to an assembly, creating an instance of it and pulling out the methodinfo for the functions I need.  This appears to work.  The type information is different for the different libraries as expected, but whenever I instantiate it it still appears to only load the registered dll, since it crashes and burns with an access violation if I call a function that is not in the currently registered dll.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
[DllImport("oleaut32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern void LoadTypeLibEx(String strTypeLibName, RegKind regKind, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out Object typeLib);

public enum RegKind
{
  RegKind_Default = 0,
  RegKind_Register = 1,
  RegKind_None = 2
}

private void Initialize() {

  Type ct;
  object typeLib;

  try {
    // Load DLL
    LoadTypeLibEx(@"c:\temp\zkA11C\zkemkeeper.dll", RegKind.RegKind_None, out typeLib);

    if (typeLib == null)
      throw new Exception("LoadTypeLibEx returned null pointer");

    TypeLibConverter converter = new TypeLibConverter();
    ConversionEventHandler eventHandler = new ConversionEventHandler();
    AssemblyBuilder zkA11C = converter.ConvertTypeLibToAssembly(typeLib, "zkA11C.dll", 0, eventHandler, null, null, null, null);

    // Get class type
    ct = zkA11C.GetType("zkA11C.CZKEMClass");

    // Create instance of the class
    dllClassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(ct);

    // Get method info for functions
    fmiConnect = ct.GetMethod("Connect_Net");
    ...
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception("Failed to load library: " + e.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Research "registration-free COM" and "activation contexts" (CreateActCtx, etc.). I think it should be possible to create three manifest files (one for each vendor library) and load the manifest of your choice at runtime (by creating an activation context and activating/deactivating it). This probably won't let you communicate with more than one vendor DLL on the same thread at once, but should let you round-robin between them. I've successfully used these technologies to use a COM DLL from C# without registering it, but fully solving your problem may take (at least) several days of work...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Registration free com is something I had earmarked to look into, but not activation contexts.  Hopefully it will be possible to use more than one at a time since these things communicate in real time, but even so, it will be a step up from where I am at the moment where I have to maintain three different builds of the software.